# How to make subitem in menu dropdown dock under li not under the nav

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I have made a menu with dropdown completely in css and I have a bit of difficulty to dock the subitems under the li being hovered.

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/diluant/jyLp2t5z/6/)

Instead it docks under the whole nav structure. I know it's something to do with the - top: 100%;

```
nav ul ul {
        background: #2A3E53; 
        border-radius: 0px; 
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute; 
        top: 100%;
    }
```

What do I have to do to make it dock under the li and push the rest of the items, any suggestions?

**Solution** from Michele Fenu's answer :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    nav ul ul {
        position: static;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understand your question, try changing this

```
nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 100%; 
    top:0;
}
```

into this

```
nav ul ul ul {
    position: static; 
    left: 100%; 
    top:0;
}
```

Here's  a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michelefenu/3czuqaa9/1/)

Comment: Ok it works but i have to put it in the @media query at breaking point and on the nav ul ul instead of nav ul ul ul. Perfect!